# Any function of jointly iid pair is iid (WLLN)?

Tags: econometrics

In Hansen (2019) p.221, I don't understand "Specifically, the fact that $(y_i, x_i)$ are mutually independent and identically distributed implies that any function of $(y_i, x_i)$ is iid, including $x_i$ $x_i'$ and $x_i y_i"$. Is there any theorem related to this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can find this in the chapter on multivariate disitributions in Hogg et al's book on mathematical statistics

Comment: What does it mean for $f(x_i,y_i)$ to be iid? The distribution of $f(x_i,y_i)$ is independent of what and identical to what?

Comment: @Angela Richardson. It means that the $z_i \equiv f(x_i,y_i)$ are iid.

Comment: Identical distributions follows from the "Transformations of Random Variables Theorem".

Comment: and independence is also a consequence ot the "Transformations of Random Variables Theorem"

Comment: Thank you all! :)

Comment: @AngelaRichardson Independence is a property of random variables not of distributions that random variables follow.